# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in jquery trigger function

Tags: jquery, html

Why does this code give me an error when the `trigger` function executes? Please tell me the solution.

```
<input />
<input />
<div id='dd'></div>
```

```js
x = $('input');
x.on("input", function() {
  n = $(this).val();

  if (x.eq(0).val() == n) { 
    $('#dd').html(n); 
  }

  if (x.eq(1).val() == n) {
    x.eq(0).val(n);
    x.eq(0).trigger("input");
  }
});
```

This jQuery code gives me an error in the browser console, but I don't know why.

> jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>           at String.replace ()
>           at Function.htmlPrefilter (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
>           at k.fn.init. (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
>           at _ (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
>           at k.fn.init.html (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
>           at HTMLInputElement. (userscript.js:5)
>           at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
>           at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
>           at Object.trigger (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
>           at HTMLInputElement. (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)

Comment: You're triggering an `input` event in an `input` event handler...

Comment: Don't trigger the input event if `this === x[0]`

Comment: You're creatubg a loop. Your event is called in your event handler filling up the stack that jQuery uses to handle eventlisteners and triggers.

Comment: add an `else` in front of `if (x.eq(1).val() == n)` - it hits both checks but you (probably) only want one check as you never update `x.eq(1)`

Comment: please tell me solution, please help me

Comment: i found the solution where i used `if(x.eq(0).val() == n)` i replaced with `if(x.index(this) == 0)` then error is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution where i used `if(x.eq(0).val() == n)` i replaced with `if(x.index(this) == 0)` then error is gone.

```js
x = $('input');
x.on("input", function() {
  n = $(this).val();

  if (x.index(this) == 0) {
    $('#dd').html(n);
  }

  if (x.index(this) == 1) {
    x.eq(0).val(n);
    x.eq(0).trigger("input");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<input />
<div id='dd'></div>
```